# How to detect hover status of group of Expandable Table Row in React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, hover, mouseover

I want to show/hide an Edit button based on hover status of table row. So I use `useHover` hooks from [this website](https://usehooks.com/useHover/) which the implementation is like this :

```js
function useHover() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const handleMouseOver = () => setValue(true);
  const handleMouseOut = () => setValue(false);
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const node = ref.current;
      if (node) {
        node.addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
        node.addEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut);
        return () => {
          node.removeEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
          node.removeEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut);
        };
      }
    },
    [ref.current] // Recall only if ref changes
  );
  return [ref, value];
}
```

So currently my component structure roughly like this (just following the example from [their docs](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#collapsible-table)):

```js
function Row(props) {
  const [hoverRef, isHovered] = useHover();
  return (
    <>
      {/* attach the hoverRef in this TableRow */}
      <TableRow ref={hoverRef}>
        <TableCell>Simplified Info here</TableCell>

        {/* I want this Edit button only displayed when someone hover the row and its 'child' group*/}
        <div className={clsx(!isHovered && { visibility: "hidden" })}>
          <IconButton>
            <EditIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
      </TableRow>

      {props.details.map((detail) => (
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>
            <Collapse>
              <Text>Detailed information Here</Text>
              
              {/* I also want to display this if the parent is hovered or this cell is hovered */}
              <div className={clsx(!isHovered && { visibility: "hidden" })}>
                <IconButton>
                  <EditIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </div>
            </Collapse>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

It is not fully work as I expect (Show Edit button on hover) since it only display edit button if only if the user hover their mouse over the `<TableRow>Simplified Info</TableRow>` Row. Want I want to do is to make both edit buttons also displayed for 2 cases:

1. the user mouse is hovering the 'parent' row
2. the user mouse is hovering one of its 'child' row

So I change the structure by wrapping the `<TableRow>` inside a `div` and attach the hover ref into that `div` like this:

```js
function Row() {
  const [hoverRef, isHovered] = useHover();
  return (
    <>
      {/* Now adding div and attach the hoverRef into this div */}
      <div ref={hoverRef}>
        <TableRow ref={hoverRef}>
          <TableCell>Simplified Info here</TableCell>

          {/* Now this edit button also displayed even if the mouse is on top of its children*/}
          <div className={clsx(!isHovered && { visibility: "hidden" })}>
            <IconButton>
              <EditIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        </TableRow>

        {props.details.map((detail) => (
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
              <Collapse>
                <Text>Detailed information Here</Text>

                {/* This button also displayed even if the mouse is hovering its parent */}
                <div className={clsx(!isHovered && { visibility: "hidden" })}>
                  <IconButton>
                    <EditIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </div>
              </Collapse>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Yes it works but it breaks the style.

Here is some illustration that might help you to understand what I want to achieve (the group of row should be highlighted & edit buttons should be displayed) :
[image: Group of row]

**So The question is**: Is there any advice on how to 'listen' to hover state of the parent and its children / siblings without breaking the style ?

Answer (score 0):

With this informations **I can't reproduce exactly to check the styles**, but to answer your question, you can try use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` from `Table` (or others elements as `div`) to listen when the elements is hovered.

One example to do this:

```
import { Table, TableCell, TableRow, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const details: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4];

export default function TableRowComponent() {
    const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const openHover = () => setIsHovered(true);
    const closeHover = () => setIsHovered(false);

    return (
        <Table onMouseEnter={openHover} onMouseLeave={closeHover}>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Simplified Info here</TableCell>
                <span className="">{isHovered && <button>{`I'm a button to edit`}</button>}</span>
            </TableRow>

            {details.map((detail) => (
                <TableRow key={detail}>
                    <TableCell>
                        <Typography>Detailed information Here</Typography>
                    </TableCell>
                    <span className="">{isHovered && <button>{`I'm a button to edit`}</button>}</span>
                </TableRow>
            ))}
        </Table>
    );
}
```

Notes: I'm using @mui v5+, and I'm using Typescript.

In this example the button is showed when the mouse is hovering in any row/element.